# Does anyone know how to block Evony?

Tags: advertising, google-adsense

There are lots of posts on Google's forums about Evony and their shady tactics:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/AdSense/thread?tid=7c9ef267b8b3c01f&hl=en

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/AdSense/thread?tid=504b2e4035058e1d&hl=en

evonyonline.com definitely doesn't work any more.

I don't know why Google doesn't stop these monkeys.

Does anyone know how to nuke Evony's latest garbage? I have about twenty filters but I am still seeing Evony ads on my site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the end of the forum topic you posted, a Google employee says you should block **evonytwo.com** (although some users still report problems). There are also various posts with long lists of URLs to block.

Personally I haven't seen an evony ad on my site since I blocked evonyonline.com but I don't know if that's because of the blocking or just because AdSense is deciding the ads are not relevant to my site any more.

Comment: Are there any sites for which Evony ads are relevant?

Comment: Touché, @Kinopiko :)